# Can someone explain to me why the submenus of my navigation bar are on the same line?

Tags: css, navigation

can someone explain to me why the sub-menus of my navigation bar are on the same line and why does the about bar become so big when hovered on? I would like them to be below each other. Here's my [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjzKWb).

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Approach</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get In Touch</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav li ul {
  display: none;
}

nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: But when I do that, nothing happens when I hover on about ;( .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `overflow:hidden` from the `ul` and then position the submenus absolutely.

```css
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Approach</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Class</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Get In Touch</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the ul `overflow: hidden` and that's why it doesn't appear. Then, you need to position the .submenu element absolutely.

CSS

```
.navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

ul > li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: none;
}
```

Result when hovering:

[image]

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadeed/pen/cd2933979959029b96e3c338e7c2e42a/)**